# scrollTop=0 browser compatibility issue

Tags: firefox, safari, cross-browser, scrolltop

I am creating a simple website that has a sidebar with buttons that link to different pages that load in an IFrame to the right. I want the pages to always load at the top- therefore added this code in the head tag of the child pages:

```
<head>`<script type='text/javascript'> parent.document.body.scrollTop = 0
```

`

It works in Safari but not Firefox.... why? What will work in both browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I have used $(window).scrollTop(0); in the past. See if this works for you.